# Recalibration a regression model by minimising the losses on month level and overall

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe shown below (it's a sample, the original dataframe is huge) and I am trying different ways to calibrate my Predicted Loss = `(0.92*(EXP(-0.07)*Price))`.

```
ObsMonth      Price   Predicted Loss  Actual Loss    
1/11/2019   4.00    3.43            4.00           
1/11/2019   10.00   8.58            9.00            
1/11/2019   20.00   17.16           19.00           
1/12/2019   44.00   37.74           39.00           
1/12/2019   66.00   56.61           58.00          
1/12/2019   7.00    6.00            15.00            
1/12/2019   9.00    7.72            8.00           
...
```

I've fit linear regression on my data and it seems like the coefficient I am getting from my linear regression doesn't estimate loss really well when aggregated on obsmonth.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(price.reshape(-1, 1), loss)
print(reg.coef_)
```

For example :

```
obsmonth    Predicted Loss (Linear regression)    Actual Loss    Diff
1/11/2019     350                                  400            -50
1/12/2019     360                                  419            -59
1/1/2020      409                                  439            -30
```

```
Total Absolute Difference = 139
```

The way I am calculating the predicted loss as a function of price by using this equation i.e. Predicted Price = `(0.92*(EXP(-0.07)*Price))` As you can see I am underestimating the loss, so what I want to do is I want to calibrate the above equation so as to minimise the overall difference between the Predcited loss and Actual loss per observation month .

What I want to do is , I want to change exponential let's say `(0.92*(EXP(-0.07)*Price))` to `(0.92*(EXP(-0.08)*Price))` and checking whether I get close to overall Actual Loss per month. I only want to change the exponential part and run my loop till I get an optimum solution which is my Predicted loss closer to my actual loss per month and also minimising the total absolute difference.

Comment: how close do you want to them to be?

Comment: I want to iterate through each month (aggregated), check where my minimum difference is 0 and then taking average of all the coefficients for each month to come up with my final coefficient

Comment: what if it's impossible to have  a difference of 0?

Comment: We can use the minimum difference as well